# If $(2^b-1+c^b)^a = (2^a-1+c^a)^b,$ then is it true that $a=b?$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, real-numbers

> **Question**: Assume that $a,b,c$ are real numbers such that
>   $$1\leq a\leq b, \quad\text{and}\quad  0<c<1.$$
>   If we have 
>   $$(2^b-1+c^b)^a = (2^a-1+c^a)^b,$$
>   then is it true that 
>   $$a=b?$$

I can only prove that the statement is true if $a$ is an integer. 
In particular, since 
$$(2^b-1+c^b)^a = (2^a-1+c^a)^b,$$
by manipulation, we have 
$$2^a = (2^b-1+c^b)^{\frac{a}{b}} -c^a+1. $$
Since LHS is an even natural number, so is RHS.
This forces $a=b.$

However, I have no idea how to prove it for real number $a.$

Comment: If $a<b,$ then $(2^b-a+c)^{\frac{a}{b}}$ is not an integer.

Comment: I see, sorry. I had mistakenly thought that $c$ was also an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
f(a,b,c)=a\cdot\ln\Big(2^b-1+c^b\Big)-b\cdot\ln\Big(2^a-1+c^a\Big)
$$
Obviously your statement is equal to finding roots of $f$.

Now, its easy to see that $f(a,b,1)=0$, so we take the derivative:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}= \frac{ab}{c(2^b-1+c^b)(2^a-1+c^a)}(2^ac^b-2^bc^a+c^a-c^b)
$$
Notice that the last term can be estimated as 
$$
2^ac^b-2^bc^a+c^a-c^b\leq2^bc^b-2^bc^a+c^a-c^b=(2^b-1)(c^b-c^a)<0
$$
due to $1\leq a<b$ and $0\leq c \leq 1$. Thus, $f$ is strictly decreasing in $c$ and hence has no other roots other than $c=1$, for $a\neq b$.

Comment: Is there a typo in your function $f$?

Comment: Yes, there was! :-)

Comment: Why is it $f(a,b,1) = 0?$ If $a=b,$ then I can see why. But if $a\neq b,$ then I couldn't deduce the equality.

Comment: Note that $f(a,b,1)=a\cdot\ln(2^b)-b\cdot\ln(2^a)=ab\cdot\ln2-ab\cdot\ln2=0$.

Comment: I see. Thank so much.